# How to use Ionic native - MS Adal in ionic project?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, adal

I'm new to Ionic and I want to authenticate the user using Azure. So I'm using MS ADAL Ionic Native in my project. I couldn't find any proper example online. Here is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { MSAdal, AuthenticationContext, AuthenticationResult } from '@ionic- 
native/ms-adal';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(private msAdal: MSAdal,platform: Platform, statusBar: 
              StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
       platform.ready().then(() => {

           let authContext: AuthenticationContext= 
this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');

  authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net', '[My-appID]', 'http://localhost:8000')
    .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
       console.log('Token is' , authResponse.accessToken);
       console.log('Token will expire on', authResponse.expiresOn);
    })
    .catch((e: any) => 
    alert(e));
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();
     });
   }
 }
```

I'm getting the following error.

> TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "userId" of AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenAsync:Expected String,but got Function.

Comment: I have a also same problem. So i set to bountry so someone help to you.

Comment: Can you please create demo at https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar This should not happen. Can you try by passing userId (optional) parameter value null ? authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net', '[My-appID]', 'http://localhost:8000', null)

Comment: ok let's try once  again. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Iam updated your code. I got this type of error. Wrong type for parameter "extraQueryParameters" of AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenAsync: Expected String, but got Function.

Comment: this error coming back in the catch or when you build it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got a work around for the issue, i'm posting my answer below. If anyone is facing the same issue they can try this.

**Sending empty string for userId and extraQueryParameters in acquireTokenAsync function solved the issue for me.**

```
let authContext: AuthenticationContext=
this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');
authContext.acquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", "[My-appID]",
"http://localhost:8000","","")
.then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
console.log('Token is' , authResponse.accessToken);
console.log('Token will expire on', authResponse.expiresOn);
})
.catch((e: any) =>
alert(e));
```

Comment: I am looking for same but can you explain which url i have passed and what is my app id.

Comment: Like what is url passing in createauthencationcontext and acuiredtokenasync?

Comment: Yes. But I want window authentication in ionic 3

Comment: Hi @Rathnakara S,
This worked for me but after successfully login my app is again redirected to the Microsoft login page. Can you help me in this ?